# How to tell when the DLC is working?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm in true vault hunter mode and bought the DLC that allows you to level up to 61. I'm at 50 now. How do I know the DLC is working?

Comment: ... what game are you playing?

Comment: @TZHX tvhm probably means True Vault Hunter Mode, which means he's playing Borderlands 2.

Comment: please, try to explain more what you are having issues.

Comment: add your gamer tag to your profile on here....I can help you with legendaries...I'll add you....Comment back to let me know you did

Answer (score 1):

If you are already at level cap, you won't see "+100 XP" lines pop up on the screen when you are killing enemies. Just go out an kill anyone - if you are not a level cap, you'll always get at least +1 XP.

Also the experience bar would slowly fill up. If you play for some time at level 50 and the bar is still completely empty - something is wrong and your DLC did not register.

Comment: Oh im rickes76 on bl2

Comment: @user70408 mkay

Answer (score 0):

You might have to beat the final boss again and then choose the option to start the 3rd play through, and like Orc JMR said you won't get xp gain or see it if the dlc isn't working. Also in the first one I remember there was a way to check for DLC, I cannot remember if there was in the 2nd or not. It would be on the main menu somewhere if it was.

Comment: Thanks yes im playing bl2 ive got some legendaries finally with other help im leval 58 now thying to get doc mercy to drop. It is painful. I a question? Ok i got the lev 50 hell fire the i got a green level 57 mg fire weapon with better stats than the hell fire so why isnt it nearly as good with same statz but better?

Comment: So the hellfire has the chance to burn right? Get this though the fire stacks, which means it causes way more damage over time than any other burning smg. That is why the hellfire is good, it causes more than one fire on the enemy.